# CMS editor removing DIV without content

Tags: magento-enterprise, cms

I'm creating a mailchimp form in CMS page but this line of code is removed once I saved it. That's why once I send a form, no validation to a user if their request was sent or not.

```
<div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
```

How can I make it stay?

Thanks!

Comment: At least 3 of us disagree :) Please lift the hold on this question.

Comment: why this question put on hold? the others understand my question and answer directly on the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@programmer_rkt provides a good solution, but have you tried something simpler; just putting in some filler text?

If those are response containers their content will likely get replaced before shown anyway. eg:

```
<div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none">Try this!</div>
```

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, I do not observe this on the CE 1.7 version I just tested on. In other words, the `div` was preserved, even if empty.

Answer (score 0):

By default, all elements without any content get deleted when saving a CMS page.This is not a bug and it is how cms page WYSWIG works by default. So instead of doing this, you really need to include a block in cms page and put your div tag inside the block.

For example you can try this code.

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" name="block.for.form.validation" template="custom/form/validation.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Put this in the layout update inside `Design` tab under `Layout Update XML` for cms page. Now create `validate.phtml` in the required directory.

File : `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/custom/form/validation.phtml`

```
<div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response. I'll try this.